# Issue with reading file on Spring Portlets Build with Maven on Websphere Portal

Tags: java, file-io, maven-3, websphere-portal, spring-portlet-mvc

I am using Spring portlets on IBM Websphere Portal 8.0, to built a file upload kind of utilty. Here I am trying to upload an XML file. The code I've written  to read it works perfectly fine when I build it normally with  RAD and installed as WAR  **but it doesn't work when it is  Build with MAVEN and installed as WAR. It gives BufferedInputStream.availabel returned as -1 all the times and hence the content of the file is not readable**
Below is  the code giving issue -

```
final BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
            new DataInputStream(request.getPortletInputStream()));
if (inputStream.available() != -1) {
    System.out.println(" inside inputStream.available() != -1");
}
```

And JSP is

```
<form name="FileUploadBasicForm" id="FileUploadBasicForm" method="POST" 
    action="${submitfileURL}" enctype="multipart/form-data"><label align="center"> <strong>title </strong></label><br><br>
    <input type="file" name="uploadfile" size="45"> <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload"> 
</form>
```

I want this code to be run and return me  the input stream so that I can run other piece of code. 
But the  it only fails when I have Build this code with MAVEN. I've tried to run this with only data input stream and getPortletInputStream but it fails for all cases.  But  the same works with RAD build .war.

Comment: FYI request is actionResuest.

Comment: Compare the jars included in web-inf/lib between the two. Maven may be including transitive dependencies that conflict with a parent classloader. I suggest updating the post with the list of jars in the target web-inf/lib of the mvn build (or the list of differences).

Comment: MAVEN---------------
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
ilwwcm-api.jar
ilwwcm-api-impl.jar
ilwwcm-commons-utils.jar
poi-3.10-FINAL.jar
spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar

Comment: spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar

Comment: RAD -- aopalliance-1.0.jar
spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar

Comment: @scotth I've tried to keep  same files as well in both  and then test it . Still the same.  How ever there is an custom shared  library  which also has same spring jars included in project so. I've removed all external spring jars and used only custom shared lib jar.  but results were same.

Comment: Doesn't it seem that getPortletInputStream() is getting blocked somewhere? I am just guessing

Answer (score 1):

Please go thru the below HCL Digital Experience Infocentre URL. You will get full idea of how WCM API works.

https://help.hcltechsw.com/digital-experience/8.5/wcm/wcm_rest_crud_content.html?hl=wcm%2Capis
https://help.hcltechsw.com/digital-experience/8.5/wcm/wcm_dev_api.html

To use the Web Content Manager API, you have 2 options:

Write your code as JSPs that you deploy on your server in your Java enterprise application. These JSPs can then be used in your Web Content Manager content by using JSP components or custom JSPs in elements.
Write you code as a compiled java enterprise application. In this case, you need to create a project in your development environment that has the two JAR files ilwwcm-api.jar and wp.base.jar in the build path. These JAR file files can be copied from your portal server from here:
/opt/WebSphere/PortalServer/wcm/prereq.wcm/wcm/shared/app/ilwwcm-api.jar
/opt/WebSphere/PortalServer/base/wp.base/shared/app/wp.base.jar
This code can then be used in your Web Content Manager content by using custom plug-ins. See How to create custom plug-ins for further information.